# Noetherian submodules and isomorphisms

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noetherian

Suppose $M$ is an $A$-Module, and $N$ is a submodule of $M$. Let
$f:N\to M$ be an $A$-module *epimorphism*. How could I show that if $N$ is noetherian, then $f$ is an *isomorphism*?

Thanks

Comment: Not much, i know that the point of the exercice is to show that Ker f=0 or that if f(n1)=f(n2) then n1=n2.  I know that N is noetherian, so i know there is a ascending chain on submodules. But other than that, i dont even know how to start

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer for the case M=N:

---

Let $x\in \ker f$. Consider $\ker f \subseteq \ker f^2 \subseteq \dotsb$ . 
 Since $N$ is noetherian, for some $t$ we have $\ker f^t = \ker f^{t+1}$. 
Since $f^t$ is surjective (`because f is surjective`), there exists $y\in M$ such that $f^t(y)=x$. So $f^{t+1}(y)=f(x)=0$. Hence $y\in \ker f^{t+1}=\ker f^t$. So $x=f^t(y)=0$.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: J.M. I edited answer, so that if you want , you can remove acceptation. :)

Comment: can you tell me why your proof does not work if M is not equal to N?

Comment: let $x\in M-N.$ let f(y)=x. then ff(y)=f(x) is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, where $N$ and $M$ are not necessarily equal, suppose $f$ is not injective, and let $K_0=\ker(f)$ and $L_0=N$. Then we have inclusions of modules
$$0<K_0<L_0=N\leq M,$$
with $L_0/K_0\cong M$.

Submodules of $L_0$ containing $K_0$ correspond to submodules of $L_0/K_0\cong M$. More precisely, there is an inclusion-preserving bijection from the set of submodules of $L_0$ containing $K_0$ to the set of submodules of $M$ given by $V\mapsto f(V)$.

Let $K_1$ and $L_1$ be those corresponding to $K_0$ and $L_0$: i.e., $K_1=f^{-1}(K_0)$ and $L_1=f^{-1}(L_0)$. Then we have
$$0<K_0<K_1<L_1\leq L_0=N\leq M,$$
with $L_1/K_1\cong M$.

Repeating, we get an infinite ascending chain
$$0<K_0<K_1<\dots$$
of submodules of $N$, contradicting the assumption that $N$ is Noetherian.

Comment: I understand you are using the correspondence theorem. However, i dont understand the following : " Let $K_1$ and $L_1$ be those corresponding to $K_0$ and $L_0$. All we know is that we have an $A_0$ a submodule of $L_0$ that contains $K_0$. How can you associate it with $L_1$ and $K_1$ ?